# How to create Stored Queries in MS Access at runtime using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2007

I am working on windows application. Here I need to create stored queries at runtime in MS Access 2007. (i.e on button click) for the Select, Insert, Update, delete, How to call the queries from the form based on the parameters ?

```
cmmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblCustomers ([CustomerID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, CustomerName Text(50), [CategoryID] Long REFERENCES tblCategories (CategoryID), [IsActive] YesNo, [ModifiedBy] Long REFERENCES tblUsers (UserID), [ModifiedDate] Date)";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Above Create table tblCustomers executed successfully,  

cmmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE prAddCustmer (CustName Text(50), CatID Long, Inact No, ModBY Long, ModDate date ) AS INSERT INTO tblCustomers  (CustomerName , CategoryID, Inactive, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate) VALUES(CustName, [CatID], [Inac], [ModBy], [ModDate]);";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//But got error in Create Procedure prAddCustomers, Please find error in the Stored query and suggest the correct answer 
//Syntax error in PARAMETER clause.
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to call a query already existing in your db, or do you want to create a query in your db ?

Comment: I need to create stored query first and then I should call it from other instance. first I need to create database and its objects like tables, stored queries first. Now I have created database and tables, and left with stored queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a new stored query in your Access database you should simply prepare a command and execute it.

For example, supposing you have a customer table and you want to retrieve the record of a single customer using a query.

To create the query

```
 string cmdText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE Customer_SelectOne (custID Long) as
     SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE IDCustomer = [custID]";
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To call the query, it is again a simple command flagged as `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

```
 string cmdText = "Customer_SelectOne";
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("custID", customerID);
 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The example above is really simple. For more complex scenario, you need to look at the reference in the area of [MS-Access Data Definition Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn125729%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

**EDIT**

Syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName 
                 (optional list of parameters with type and size for Text)
                    AS
                 (Valid SQL Statement using the optional parameters list)
```

so this should be your 'prAddCustomers'

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE prAddCustomers 
                     (CustName Text(50), 
                      CatID Long, 
                      IsActive BIT, 
                      ModBY Long, 
                      ModDate DATETIME )
                    as
                    INSERT INTO tblCustomers 
                      (CustomerName, CategoryID, IsActive, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate) 
                    VALUES([CustName], [CatID], [IsActive], [ModID],[ModDate])";
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, I have added insert statement which has errors, Please review the question once again and suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: This is a different problem. Your SQL Syntax is wrong. Try to write the same query in MS-Access and copy/paste in your code. I see also that you don't pass correctly the parameters to your query. (They should go with type before the AS) Look carefully to my example

Comment: I have edited the code and got "Syntax error in PARAMETER clause". Please tell where is the error ?

Comment: The datatype for YesNo fields is called BIT

Comment: Also not sure about DATE type. It should be DATETIME

Comment: In my case everything works fine but I can not see the created Procedure not in VS nor in MS Access

Comment: I suggest you to write a new question and clarify in it why this answer is not working for you. Please put as many details as you can.